# Python Panda dynamic writing results in excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

what i am trying to do here is to take all the sql from an excel, execute them using python and export the data to another excel called output.xlsx. However, the results overwrite the result that comes before. How should i change the code below so whenever a sql run, the result would be saved in a new tab? Thank you !

```
sql = excel_data_df['Query'].tolist()

i = 0
while i < len(sql):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    stmn = (sql[i])
    print(stmn)
    cursor.execute(stmn)
    while True:
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        if row is None:
            break
            print("row is null")
        print(row)
        res2 = cursor.fetchall()
        res2=pd.DataFrame(res2)
       writer2=pd.ExcelWriter('C:\\Python\Excel\output.xlsx')
       res2.to_excel(writer2,'Sheet1')
       writer2.save()
```

Comment: you're not incrementing your ```i``` in your loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

- As @ewong mentioned, increment the loop counter
- Change the sheet name at each loop
- Open the excel file before the loop, then save it after the loop ends

Try this code:

```
sql = excel_data_df['Query'].tolist()

i = 0
writer2=pd.ExcelWriter('C:\\Python\\Excel\\output.xlsx')  # open excel file
while i < len(sql): 
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    stmn = (sql[i])
    print(stmn)
    cursor.execute(stmn)   
    while True:  
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        if row is None:  
            break
            print("row is null")  # will never get here
        print(row)
        res2 = cursor.fetchall() 
        res2 = pd.DataFrame(res2)
        res2.to_excel(writer2,'Sheet' + str(ctr+1))  # create new sheet 
        ctr += 1
writer2.save()  # save full excel file
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, its overwriting the result in the excel and i have only 1 sheet in the excel after all. Can you please tell me how to modify it? Many Thanks